# Is my binary search tree correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I must construct a binary search tree for the predefined identifiers in the order of ORD, CHR, WRITE, SEEK, PRED, EOF, WRITELN, BOOLEAN, PAGE, GET, TRUE, COPY, POT, ABS

I am thinking I got it right but I wasn't sure where WRITELN went. Does it go to the left of WRITE or right of WRITE? 
[image]

Comment: It depends on how your ordering is defined, but I think it is most conventional to place `WRITELN` after `WRITE` and thus to the right in the tree.

Comment: Apart from that, your tree looks correct to me.